# Make Migration Conditional in Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-migrations, django-1.8

The concrete use case is:

> [A Django module](https://github.com/incuna/django-pgcrypto-fields) wants to create an extension during migration. If
>   the DB user that is used to run the migration is not superuser, this
>   fails.

There are several ways to solve this, one way being (hypothetically) to check in the migration file whether the extension is installed and only run that SQL code if it is not installed.

After some research, however, it does not seem that Django's `RunSQL` can return results and subsequently excluding operations depending on the result of a previous operation is not possible. Would there be any other ways to achieve this? (E.g. subclassing `RunSQL`?)

Any solution based on Django migrations, Django settings or Postgres internal (one SQL statement that achieves to run `CREATE EXTENSION` only if a certain condition is true) would be fine.

(Note that I mentioned django-pgcrypto-fields only for illustration. I'm interested to know whether such a solution exists in general.)

EDIT in answer to Anentropic's comment:
The solution has to work when running the `test` or `jenkins` commands. This means, manually calling `--fake-initial` or similar to avoid running this migration is not an option. If you can explain how to make `test` fake certain migrations, this is most welcome.

My current solution is to add the following to `settings`:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'pgcrypto_fields': 'do-not-run-migrations'
}
```

But this will disable all of the migrations in question and not only the offending one. In this case, it might work, but I see this as a lucky and ugly work around.

Comment: The module needs the extension in order to work, so you need to find a way to create the extension. I would suggest to create extension as admin user then [fake](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake) the migration in question

Comment: @Anentropic Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this won't work with `manage.py test`, imho. I have edited my question in answer to your comment.

Comment: if it's for running tests I'd suggest to use different db settings for tests, your django db user could be given admin access on the test db

Comment: I'm aware that there are other ways to solve the concrete use case. But what I really would like to know if there is a way to run migration operations based on certain conditions (be it by code in the migration files, be it by the SQL code itself, be it by Django settings). I've just added the use case as an example.

Comment: if you wrote the migration you can do things conditionally, I guess it's going to be hard/impossible for 3rd party migrations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, Django's [HStoreExtension](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#django.contrib.postgres.operations.HStoreExtension) does only run if necessary. But of course, it still requires superuser access. For pgcrypto, a class analogous to HStoreExtension could be created.

The setup for making it run in tests still requires superuser access, so the settings have to look like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django.contrib.postgres',
    ...
)

if sys.argv[1] in ['test', 'jenkins']:
    # Install extension hstore (requires superuser)
    INSTALLED_APPS = ('test_init',) + INSTALLED_APPS

    # a superuser
    DATABASES["default"]["USER"] = 'xxx'
    DATABASES["default"]["PASSWORD"] = 'xxx'
```

and the 'test_init' django app contains only the required `__init.py__` and a migrations module with the following file `0001_initial.py`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import HStoreExtension

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    run_before = [
        ('some_app_that_requires_hstore', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        HStoreExtension(),
    ]
```

It is actually not required to check for test mode (via `sys.argv`) to make the migration only then. As mentioned above, HStoreExtension is silent about errors. So even if you run `migrate` on production without superuser it would not fail, no matter if hstore is installed yet. See its source code.

See also [Django's documentation of HStoreField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#hstorefield).